# Optimal algorithm for solving n-armed bandit problems?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

I've read about a number of algorithms for solving n-armed bandit problems like $\epsilon$-greedy, softmax, and UCB1, but I'm having some trouble sorting through what approach is best for minimizing regret.

Is there a known optimal algorithm for solving the n-armed bandit problem? Is there a choice of algorithm that seems to perform best in practice?

Comment: Presumably there is not a recognised optimal solution, as otherwise the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) would say so and there would not be an experimental [Sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bandit/)

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Theoretical Computer Science SE?

Comment: @mbq since reinforcement learning is a branch of machine learning, I don't think so ;)

Comment: @steffen Sure, the name seemed "tcsy".

Comment: @mbq I don't get it. What does "tscy" mean ?

Comment: @steffen: TCS-y (Theoretical Computer Science)-y.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two survey papers I have found recently. I have not read them yet, but the abstracts sound promising.

[Joann`s Vermorel and Mehryar Mohri: Multi-Armed Bandit Algorithms and Empirical Evaluation](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/pub/bandit.pdf) (2005)

From the abstract:

> The multi-armed bandit problem for a gambler is to decide
>   which arm of a K-slot machine to pull to maximize his total reward in
>   a series of trials. Many real-world learning and optimization problems
>   can be modeled in this way. Several strategies or algorithms have been
>   proposed as a solution to this problem in the last two decades, but, to our
>   knowledge, there has been no common evaluation of these algorithms.

[Volodymyr Kuleshov and Doina Precup: Algorithms for the multi-armed bandit problem](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~vkules/bandits.pdf) (2000)
From the abstract:

> Secondly, the performance of
>   most algorithms varies dramatically with the parameters of the bandit problem. Our study
>   identiﬁes for each algorithm the settings where it performs well, and the settings where it performs poorly.